# Como fazer vários inserts de uma só vez?

Tags: php, mysql

Bom eu tenho 3 tabelas no meu banco de dados, e eu faço um `INSERT` na tabela **venda**, e assim que eu insiro os dados nela automaticamente teria que inserir nas tabelas **vendaservicos** e na tabela **vendaproduto** que seria esse código :

```
if(isset($_POST['send'])){
$venda = $_POST['num_venda'];
$data = $_POST['data_venda'];
$placa = $_POST['placa'];
$km = $_POST['km'];
$produtos = $_POST['produtos'];
$servicos = $_POST['servicos'];


include ('banco.php');


mysql_query("INSERT INTO venda(id_venda, num_venda, data_venda, placa, km, produtos, servicos)
        values(
            NULL,
            '{$venda}',
            '{$data}',
            '{$placa}',
            '{$km}',
            '{$produtos}',
            '{$servicos}'

                        )
        ");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO vendaproduto (id, id_venda, produtos)
          SELECT venda.id_venda, venda.id_venda, venda.produtos
          FROM venda");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO vendaservico (id, id_venda, servicos)
          SELECT venda.id_venda, venda.id_venda, venda.servicos
          FROM venda") ;

header("location:lista.php");}
```

Na primeira vez que eu testei o código deu certo, mas agora toda vez que eu tento não insere nas tabelas **vendaproduto** e **vendaservico**, só insere os dados na tabela de venda.

O erro é o seguinte: `Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'`

O fato de eu ainda usar o `mysql_` pode interferir em algo no meu código?

Comment: Para teste, sempre comente os `headers()` e faça sua consulta assim `mysql_query("insert ...") or die(mysql_error())`, edite a pergunta e adicione os erros.

Comment: O erro pode ser registros com valores duplicados...

Comment: Opa amigo , fiz a ediçao com o erro e testei tambem , realmente fala que esta duplicando os valores

Comment: No seu banco deve haver uma Chave Primária que não pode ser repetida.
Verifique isso.

Comment: O problema é que o seu select está sem where, então ele vai retornar todos os registros daquela tabela para inserir. Nessas tabelas existem campos auto-increment ou unique key?

Comment: os campos são auto-increment

Comment: Você quer pegar o último registro gravado em vendas e gravar nas outras tabelas?

Comment: Isso , gostaria de pega os últimos registros q eu insiro na tabela venda e gravas nas outras duas

Comment: É um registro por vez inserido em vendas certo?

Comment: Sim e so um registro por vez

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a função [mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) para pegar o ultimo registro inserido em vendas. Depois pode fazer o insert com select mas dessa vez adicione um where, que compara o id com o último registro inserido

```
if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO venda ... ")){
    $id = mysql_last_id();

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO vendaproduto (id, id_venda, produtos)
          SELECT venda.id_venda, venda.id_venda, venda.produtos
          FROM venda WHERE id = $id") or die(mysql_error());

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO vendaservico (id, id_venda, servicos)
          SELECT venda.id_venda, venda.id_venda, venda.servicos
          FROM venda WHERE id = $id") or die(mysql_error());  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Aparentemente o erro que está dando é que você está tentando inserir valores duplicados num campo de valores únicos.

Mas para inserir multiplos valores com um insert só faça assim:

```
INSERT INTO `usuarios` (`id`, `nome`, `email`) VALUES (123, 'Fulano da Silva', 'fulano@email.com'), (32, 'Ciclano', 'ciclano@uol.com.br')
```

Answer (score -2):

Você está inserindo ID's duplicados na tabela `vendaproduto` e `vendaservico`.
Se a coluna **"id"** é auto-incremental você pode omitir a coluna ID.

Ficaria da seguinte maneira:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO vendaproduto (id_venda, produtos)
      SELECT venda.id_venda, venda.produtos
      FROM venda");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO vendaservico (id_venda, servicos)
      SELECT venda.id_venda, venda.servicos
      FROM venda") ;
```

Comment: Eu tentei assim , agora inseriu so que inseriu ate de mais , foi inserido 5 linhas a mais tipo duplicando